# WCF Trace Delay

Tags: wcf, biztalk

I've configured WCF to log to a trace file and I am able to view the trace file in Microsoft Service Trace Viewer. Problem is there's a delay of approx 30 minutes between the messages being sent / received and the log record being written to file.

Anyone know why this may be?

Below I have pasted relevant content from btsntsvc64.exe.config

```
> <system.diagnostics>
>     <sources>
>       <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose">
>         <listeners>
>           <add name="xml" />
>         </listeners>
>       </source>
>       <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
>         <listeners>
>           <add name="xml" />
>         </listeners>
>       </source>
>       <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization" switchValue="Verbose">
>         <listeners>
>           <add name="xml" />
>         </listeners>
>       </source>
>     </sources>
>     <sharedListeners>
>       <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack"
> initializeData="C:\logs\BizTalk\WCFTrace.svclog" />
>     </sharedListeners>
>     <trace autoflush="true" />   </system.diagnostics>   <system.serviceModel>
>     <diagnostics>
>       <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
> logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false" />
>     </diagnostics>   </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question (why it's a comment), but if it is acceptable in your environment you may recycle the app pool which will force it to flush.